# Problem with absolute positioning in Firefox and Safari

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, position, css-position, absolute

I am currently working on a website (http://www.helmholtz-nachhaltigkeit.de/).

In Chrome everything looks nice, but somehow Firefox and Safari are making problems with my `position: absolute;` in my `container-fluid`.

As you can see it somehow accepts the `left: 0;` and `top: 0;` on the `img`, but when opened in Firefox or Safari it somehow shows a gap [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8su1.png).

I tried everything, checked every padding, but couldn't find a solution yet.

Thanks in advance!
Patrick

Comment: Interesting issue. I could not find any suitable solution yet, but a hack would be to manually move it towards the site's left / right using `translateX(1px)`.

Comment: Hm, I've checked the site in both Firefox and Safari (on MacOS) and I don't see the issue. Can we start by making sure your CSS is not cached in those browsers by clearing all site data?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem:

I converted the svg to a png and the gaps were gone!
There must have been a weird svg codeline which made those gaps.

Thanks anyway :)